# Código de comparação de datas

Tags: php

Tenho um código que compara a data atual com uma data específica e verifica se essa "entrega" esta atrasada em dia ou vence hoje por exemplo mas mesmo que seja a mesma data que a atual o else não aparece "em dia" não acontece que puder me ajudar agradeço

```
$hoje = new DateTime();

echo $hoje->format("d/m/Y");

$entrega = new DateTime('2018-07-10');

echo "<br><br>";

if ($hoje > $entrega) {
    echo "Atrasado";
    echo "<br><br>";
    $interval = $hoje->diff($entrega);
    echo "$interval->days dias";

} else if ($hoje == $entrega) {
    echo "Vence hoje";
} else {
    echo "Em dia";
}
```

Comment: Ponha o interval fora do IF e compare if $interval = 0, > 0 e > 0 com "invert" - Note que na coluna "relacionado" do lado direito do site tem mais postagens sobre o assunto (e se usar a pesquisa, vai encontrar outras)

Comment: por que vi que o invert retorna um valor booleano e não achei nenhuma pegunta que abordasse sobre contar os dias

Comment: Mais ou menos assim? $interval = $hoje->diff($entrega); if ($interval ->invert > 0) { echo "Atrasado"; echo "<br><br>"; echo "$interval->days dias"; } else if ($interval->invert === 0) { echo "Vence hoje"; } else { echo "Em dia"; }

Comment: Não entendi mas mesmo assim obrigado